# Practical examples on redis and celery

Tags: python, redis, celery

I am new to `redis` and `celery`. I have gone through the basic tutorial of both, but I am not getting how to implement then in `task scheduling job`

I am unable to start with the scripting part. I am not getting how to write a script to make a queue, run the workers etc. I would need a practical example

Comment: And what problem do you have?

Comment: @RostyslavDzinko I am unable to start with the scripting part. I am not getting how to write script for making queue, run the workers etc. means i need a practical example

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So here's a cannonical example of how can celery run with Redis (let the script filename be mytasks.py):

```
from celery import Celery

celery = Celery('tasks', broker='redis://localhost:6379/0')

@celery.task
def add(x, y):
    return x + y
```

As you see, broker argument was set to use Redis installed on your local machine. The next thing is to start celery server:

```
$ celery -A mytasks worker --loglevel=info
```

As your tasks celery server has been started, you can now use it to run your task just by importing mytasks script, e.g from Python interpreter interactive mode:

```
>>> from mytasks import add
>>> add.delay(1, 1)
2
```

After some time '2' will appear in console.

That's a basic example of how you can setup your tasks execution environment.

Comment: whats the meaning of `loglevel=info`

Comment: It's a logging setting (celery's logging is built on Python built-in logging module), read more about logging here: http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html

Comment: hey when i am running this on terminal then it is saying that `no module named as mytasks` and when i am running this through a file then it is giving the response ` Received unregistered task of type 'mytasks.add'.
The message has been ignored and discarded.

Did you remember to import the module containing this task?
Or maybe you are using relative imports?
Please see http://bit.ly/gLye1c for more information.

The full contents of the message body was:
{'retries': 0, 'task': 'mytasks.add', 'eta': None, 'args': (1, 1), 'expires': None, 'callbacks': None, 'errbacks': None, 'kwargs': {}, '
`

Comment: when i am trying to add usng add.delay(1,1), then i am getting answer as `bce3e04f-61a5-4bdf-91cd-dca751b8cc73`

Comment: The result you're showed up is a task id. Result is an object itself, which has methods, like .ready(), which resolves to True/False (if task is done of opposite), and .get(), that returns you the calculation result of the task execution.